# How do you use simple_fields_for with associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, `Wines` that `has_one :register` and `Registers` that `belong_to :wine`. The `registers_controller.rb` is straightforward, produced by `rails generate scaffold`.

I want to create a `register` object at the same time as a `wine` object and to ensure they are linked correctly. I am therefore trying to do this within the same form.

I am using `simple_form_for` and `simple_fields_for` and I believe the latter is being executed but there is no instance of `register` and so the form does not include the fields for completion.

I think the relevant code snippets are:

From `wines_controller.rb`

```
def new
  @wine = Wine.new
  @wine.register = Register.new
end
def create
  @wine = Wine.new(wine_params)
  @wine.register.build
  # error checking code
end 
def wine_params
  params.require(:wine).permit(:name, :cuvee, register_attributes: [:id, :short_name])
```

From `wines\_form.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for @wine do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<% f.simple_fields_for :register do |r| %>
  <%= r.label :short_name %>
  <%= r.input :short_name %> 
<% end %>
</div>
```

I have tried various different codes within `def create` and `def new` methods including (in `def create`) `@wine.register.build = Register.new(register_params)` and `@wine.register.build` in `def new`.

What am I doing wrong? Clearly, when I need to create one object the second needs to be instantiated in order for `simple_fields_for` to produce input areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Wine model:

```
class Wine
  has_one :register
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :register
end
```

In your Wine controller define the following new action:

```
def new
  @wine = Wine.new
  @register = @wine.build_register
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @wine do |w| %>
  <%= w.input: :name %>
  <%= w.simple_fields_for :register do |r| %>
    <%= r.input :short_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That worked for me. So, (unless I am mistaken) the syntax is
linked_object = primary_object.method_linked object
Thanks for your help.

Comment: you're welcome! Yeah that's right, and don't forget to pluralize it in case of a `one-to-many` relationship! Also don't forget to mark the question answered ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `Wine.build_register` instead. Like this:

```
def create
  @wine = Wine.new(wine_params)
  @wine = @wine.build_register
  #other code
end
```